# Android: ScriptIntrinsicBlur error

Tags: android, blur, renderscript

I want blur to `ImageView`

This code not work and on `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` line force close

> Blur Class :

```
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 20f;


    public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
        if (null == image)
            return null;

        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
        final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

> Set blur code :

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlImage.openConnection().getInputStream());
bmp = blur(bmp);
imgPost.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

> And erro log :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL2BT.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [ScriptIntrinsicBlur documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html), the class was added in API 17 and therefore does not exist prior to that. You can use the [Renderscript Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v8-renderscript) to gain access Renderscript back to API 8, including [android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html)

Comment: Thanks, How include support.v8 ? this library exits in `build-tools\android-4.4W\renderscript\lib`

Comment: The Gradle instructions are in the link provided

Comment: I use eclipse. Can use it ?

Comment: Yep, but you'll have to dig up instructions - Eclipse was [fully deprecated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/12/android-studio-10.html) and no longer supported back in December 2014.